# Tag-Editor badge bug detected

Tags: bug, status-completed

So, I edited the [satan](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/satan) tag wiki, but was awarded the Tag Editor badge for [christian-living](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christian-living)  Stack Exchange has been lying to me, or maybe its just demon possessed!

Comment: It [looks like](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/posts/5711/revisions) you edited the [tag:christian-living] tag wiki at Feb 1 at 13:57.  Is that not true?  Maybe the badge just showed up late?  Does editing the excerpt, but no the body, count for the badge?  It is strange in any case.

Comment: I should also mention my reputation was 6666 when I did this.  Coincidence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a bug in the badge granting logic that excluded tag wiki excerpts when they were your first edit, but they *were* caught after you edited a main wiki.

This fix will be pushed out in the next build (rev > 2012.2.16.1102).